# Sorting certain info in a file

Tags: python, file, sorting, text-files

I am making a program that sorts the file alphabetically with the highest score. The file has 4 names like this separated by tabs:

```
Jeff    12    17    16
Dan     23    21   18
John    12    10   20
Mary    13    24   24
```

This is my code:

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.sort()
    fields = [line.split() for line in f]
    name, grades = fields[0], fields[1:]
    grades = [int(grade) for grade in grades]
    grades.sort()
    highest = max(grades)
with open('file.txt','w') as fout:
    for el in lines:
        fout.write('{0}\n'.format(' '.join(el)))
with open('file.txt','r') as fsort:
    for line in fsort:
        print(line[:-1])
    fsort.close()
```

I keep getting errors such as the list value is out of range; for the field line. Can someone give me a solution so that this code works?

Comment: I have a feeling that you have an empty line in your file somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fields = [line.split() for line in lines]`, not `in f`. As `f.readlines()` is called, the file pointer is moved to the end eventually, meaning `fields` was an empty list.

However, I have a feeling `name, grades = fields[0], fields[1:]` isn't going to do what you want it to. The following should make sure `name` and `grades` store what you want (large edit upon request of the asker):

```
with open("class6Afile.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lines.sort()
with open('class6AfileOut.txt','w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split()
        name, grades = fields[0], fields[1:]
        grades = [int(grade) for grade in grades]
        grades.sort()
        highest = max(grades)
        grades = [str(grade) for grade in grades]
        print name, grades
        fout.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(name, ' '.join(grades)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't that label the first column as name, and the other columns as grades?

Comment: @user3350669 Try it out, and see :). Best way to learn. Just `print name` after setting `name, grades` and see what values it has become.

Comment: @user3350669 Well for me, `name` is just simply Dan's row in the file. Which makes sense, because we ordered it alphabetically by row, and then split each row (in a list of rows `fields`) into a list of 'cell' data from the file. But `fields` is still a list of row data. So `fields[0]` is just the alphabetical first row data. Hope that made sense.

Comment: @user3350669 If you'd like me to write an answer for you that will just work, I can do. But this detective game is the best way to learn a new language.

Comment: So in that sense, in order to get all the names I would do [-1:2]?

Comment: @user3350669 In order to get all the names, you need to loop through what is currently `fields`, and take the first element from each list in `fields`. So for example, the first name is `fields[0][0]`, the second is `fields[1][0]` and so on. You can do this in a for loop such as `for row in fields: # get the first element which is now row[0]`

Comment: Could you just write the answer >.< I don't understand the reasoning for that field bit

Comment: @user3350669 Okay, I've updated my answer with the correct version of the first part of your code, it was just a rewrite of your for loop. Haven't done the rest of it, because I'm not sure what it's purpose is

Comment: Thank you:) The rest of the code is to just write to the file, so that information is saved and then print it into the python shell

Comment: @user3350669 I've updated the answer with everything working roughly as I think you want it. Have fun. If this has answered your query, marking the answer as accepted (by the voting buttons) is always appreciated :)